# core/no-app No Firebase App 'DEFAULT' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() | Android Only Error

Tags: flutter, dart

So i tried my app on android device, but the firebase didn't work like it does on iOS device. it give me `[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()`

But i did already initialize the firebase. Here's where I initialized the firebase

### Firebase Initialized :

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
  .then((_) => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Title',
        theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Poppins'
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          return ResponsiveSizer(
            builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
              return MyApp();
            },
          );
        },
      )
  )));
}
```

the app work well on iOS device but not on Android device. Here's what where i use the Firebase service

### Firebase Service call :

```
Future _getToken() async {
    var token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('otp', token);
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _getToken().then(AfterToken);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your may check you gradle files and your services.json file for android.
[add firebase to android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).